# Efficient way to stream a sequence of frames

Tags: python, opencv, flask, ffmpeg

I'm facing with an issue: I implemented a device to detect stranger for my home, which includes inputs from some IP camera and use a tensorflow model to process frame got from them.

Now I want to build a dashboard (use Flask or Django - python framework as backend) to streaming the processed frames I got from the system, and if possible, do some transform on them (such as stack multi frames into one, etc), and run the server so I can watch it from distances. Currently, I'm sending frame by frame as independent images but it costs so much bandwidth. I read how h264 encoder work and felt very exicted about it. Now, the question is, how can I use h264 or any encoder like it transfer my data and reduce the bandwidth?

Comment: some more details would help, e.g. where are the bandwidth costs a problem, between "cameras and server" or between "server and web client". I'd also suggest including a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem, stackoverflow is about solving problems with existing code

Comment: The problem is the bandwidth between "cameras and server", I think, because in case the server is not in the same LAN network with the cameras, and if I have 4 cameras, the bandwidth I needed is up to 100Mbps!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV have some [Video Encoding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ad59c61d8881ba2b2da22cff5487465b5) capabilities but `cv::VideoWriter` is intended to write to a file. You might be able to access the raw stream by writing to a device but it's a bit hacky.

If you really want to stream H264 video then you probably have better chance with GStreamer. You can easily feed it with OpenCV matrix content. I don't have an example under the hand though.

Comment: I have an security camera at home, too. When I used their android app to view from my office, I saw it didn't cost so much bandwidth as the way I'm doing now, in spite of streaming with HD quality. I'd like to perform something like that.